# How to hide a UIView and remove the "empty" space? -iOS/Monotouch

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, constraints, xamarin, autolayout

I need to be able to hide controls on a page that uses constraints and remove the empty space that `Hidden=true` leaves. It needs to be similar to how the web handles visibility. If it's invisible, it doesn't take up space.

Does anyone know of a clean way to accomplish this?

Please let me know if you need more details.
Thx

---

Example:

```
UIButton | UIButton | UIButton
"empty space for hidden UIButton"
UIButton
```

That should really be rendered like this:

```
UIButton | UIButton | UIButton
UIButton
```

Edit: I'm using Xamarin Studio and VS2012 for development.

Answer (score 3):

Since original question is related to Xamarin, I provide complete C# solution.

First, create height constraint for your view and give it an identifier in Xcode Interface Builder:

[image: Constraint Identifier]

Then in controller override ViewDidAppear() method and wrap view with HidingViewHolder:

```
    public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewDidAppear(animated);
        applePaymentViewHolder = new HidingViewHolder(ApplePaymentFormView, "ApplePaymentFormViewHeightConstraint");
    }
```

It is important to create HidingViewHolder when view was laid out, so it has real height assigned. 
To hide or show view you can use corresponding methods:

```
applePaymentViewHolder.HideView();
applePaymentViewHolder.ShowView();
```

HidingViewHolder source:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using UIKit;

/// <summary>
/// Helps to hide UIView and remove blank space occupied by invisible view
/// </summary>
public class HidingViewHolder
{
    private readonly UIView view;
    private readonly NSLayoutConstraint heightConstraint;
    private nfloat viewHeight;

    public HidingViewHolder(UIView view, string heightConstraintId)
    {
        this.view = view;
        this.heightConstraint = view
            .GetConstraintsAffectingLayout(UILayoutConstraintAxis.Vertical)
            .SingleOrDefault(x => heightConstraintId == x.GetIdentifier());
        this.viewHeight = heightConstraint != null ? heightConstraint.Constant : 0;
    }

    public void ShowView()
    {
        if (!view.Hidden)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (heightConstraint != null)
        {
            heightConstraint.Active = true;
            heightConstraint.Constant = viewHeight;
        }
        view.Hidden = false;
    }

    public void HideView()
    {
        if (view.Hidden)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (heightConstraint != null)
        {
            viewHeight = heightConstraint.Constant;
            heightConstraint.Active = true;
            heightConstraint.Constant = 0;
        }
        view.Hidden = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the code, but sadly I still have the empty space when I use this :(

Answer (score 1):

In storyboard wire your constrains first. Then try this

```
    self.viewToHideHeight.constant = 0;
    self.lowerButtonHeightFromTop.constant = self.viewToHideHeightFromTop.constant + self.viewToHideHeight.constant;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
        self.viewToHide.alpha = 0.0f;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using Xamarin (and the VS2012 plugin) and don't have access to a storyboard. The constraints are created manually. I don't have access to those properties.